# How to download aptoide source code?

Tags: android, svn, version-control

I'm going to download **aptoid-client** source code from http://www.aptoide.org/browser

 Do you know special tool or software to clone this repository?
It is using Trac Browser for browsing repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right on their [homepage](http://dev.aptoide.org/), under "Get the Source"

> To get all the source code, you must have some SVN program on your
>   computer. Then, you can check out the source code by (in linux):
>
> ```
> svn co http://aptoide.org/repo/aptoide-client/<versions do fetch> <destination folder>
> ```
>
> You can also get the unstable, bleeding edge version of the code, from
>   the unstable folder. This code is a daily snapshot For that, check out
>   as:
>
> ```
> svn co http://aptoide.org/repo/aptoide-client/unstable <destination folder>
> ```
>
> Server side code can be fetch from:
>
> ```
> svn co http://aptoide.org/repo/aptoide-server <destination folder>
> ```

Comment: I'm using tortoiseSVN, and server ask me username and password! What can i do?

Comment: Looks like they changed the URLS, can you update this
?